# Simplest way to proxy RSTP streams

Tags: streaming, rtsp, rtsp-client

Suppose we have an RTSP stream, which is outside of a companies extranet. Due to certain events, a huge number of employees are likely to view the current **live stream**. Given the number of employees is > some hundred, the outbound internet connection might not be fast enough.

Since RTSP isn't stateless, **do proxies even exist**?

Please propose **ways to proxy the RTSP stream**, so that only low bandwidth of the internet-connection gets consumer by the proxy itself.

**Do (open-source) products exist**, which I may configure or adopt to form a RTSP proxy?

Any, finally, is my question too general? Is the **payload data / encoding** of the underlying **live stream of importance** regarding my proxy question?

Comment: Technically it is not only possible to create a proxy, but also to use RTP over multicast UDP on intranet and reduce bandwidth of multiple streams to the same source.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. Are you aware of product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/streaming-server-dev/2002/Apr/msg00036.html), it could be done with Apple's QTSS (Quicktime Streaming Server). The best scenario if feasible in your network would be to retransmit the live stream in multicast to avoid overloading your LAN.